# Where is the trash that the stock camera/photos app moves to?

Tags: photos

In Android 10, if you take a photo with the stock camera/photos app (which identifies itself as either "Camera" or "Photos" in the app switcher¹) and then view it afterwards, one of the "buttons" is a trash can. If you tap it, the phone prompts you with,

> Move to trash? It will be removed from all folders. 
> [Trashcan] Move to trash

Where is the "trash" that this is being moved to, and how do I access it?

[image]

(The device is a Pixel 3a purchased directly from Google, so it should be free of the sort of junk many carriers load onto phones.)

¹The app whose icon is: 
[image]

Comment: Photos app > Menu > Bin https://www.xda-developers.com/android-11-hidden-recycle-bin-trashed-photos-videos

Answer (score 1):

According to [How can i find my recycle bin on Android? - Google Photos Community](https://support.google.com/photos/thread/91704?hl=en)

> ... trash bin and the files inside it are **not actually present on your Android device**, which is why you can't find the files.

(Emphasis added)

By implication, they are stored on cloud  and that is where you restore them from if needed. You can locate them at https://photos.google.com/trash as mentioned in [How to recovery the google photos deleted from trash - Google Photos Community](https://support.google.com/photos/thread/406055?hl=en).

I guess if you turn off sync for photos, deleted photos should be directly deleted without moving to Trash and obviously you won't find them at the location linked above.

Comment: At least on my Pixel 8 Android 14 it is: DCIM/Camera/.trashed-1709964560-PXL_20240118_001529242.mp4

Answer (score 0):

> Where is the "trash" that this is being moved to, and how do I access it?

Latest version of Photos App, *Version 5.71.0.416067338*:

**Photos App -> Library -> Trash**

Comment: AFAIK, the change was related to an update to the Google Photos app, not the Android version.

Comment: What ever the case is, I was only providing an answer to the question, as the previous answer doesn't answer the question